# Is there a way to extend the expiry of an already expired Azure sas token?

Tags: asp.net, azure

In the project I am working, SAS token is used for downloading files in Azure Blob storage. Some of those tokens have expired. I want to know whether there is any way by which the expired tokens can be extended so that they can be used again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know whether there is any way by which the expired tokens
>   can be extended so that they can be used again.

Well, the answer is both no and yes. It actually depends on how you created a SAS token.

Assuming you have **created a SAS token without using a Shared Access Policy with expiry date specified in the policy, then the answer is no**. Once a token has expired, you will need to create a new SAS token with new expiry date and use that. As such there's no mechanism to extend the expiry of an existing token.

If you have **created a SAS token using a Shared Access Policy and that has expiry date defined, then the answer is yes**. You can simply change the expiry date in the Shared Access Policy and then the same SAS token can be used.

Comment: Couldn't you use a stored access policy in the SAS token and then update the policy? Of course this could not be done per-user, but still :)

Comment: Great point. Didn't think that far :). Let me update my answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @GauravMantri Lets say I am playing a video which is 30 minutes long, and the SAS token expiration is set to 20 minutes. If I request a new SAS token will the Video resume from where it has stopped ?